# Question about Greater Galactics

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Which old (at least 30 years) SF book series had entities called Greater Galactics? It also referred to certain people as having a High Life Index.

I think the Greater Galactics were comparative supermen who ran covert missions on Earth or at least on humans. I also seem to remember that they were short stories rather than full novels. Sorry but I can't remember any other details.

Comment: I think this may be The Secret Galactics by A E Van Vogt, but I haven't read it for years and do not own a copy. I'll see what I can find online.

Comment: From reviews, perhaps not that specific book, but the description is very like A E Van Vogt's general approach to plotting so it could still be by him.

Comment: Sorry. It's been a long time since I read anything with them in. The only thing I'm sure of is the phrase, high life index which I think was a marker for those humans who had Galactics' heritage or were masquerading as ordinary humans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that "Asylum" was the first appearance of the Great Galactics. It's impossible to do justice to the complexity of a vV story, but, basically, the Dreeghs -- a kind of super-intelligent galactic vampire -- have come to the Solar System to feed.  An ordinary human resists and over the course of a dozen or so adventures (at about two pages/adventure) he turns out (to his own surprise as much as to the Dreeghs' surprise) to be a Great Galactic sent to deal with the Dreeghs.

I'm pretty sure that "Asylum" was worked into at least one fix-up novel, but I don't recall which.

Comment: A. E. Van Vogt's "Supermind", published 1977; had "Asylum," first published in 1943, "The Proxy Intelligence" in 1968 and "Research Alpha" in 1965.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mark and KenM. This is exactly the story that I've had at the back of my mind for all these decades.